# Get character typed, cross-browser

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Simple question -- Does anyone know of a reliable cross-browser function to get the ***character*** typed from a keydown event?  I can write one from the quirksmode grid but would rather not re-invent the wheel for something so simple yet so non-standard.

Let me clarify:

There is no way to do this simply using `event.keyCode` or `event.which`.  The overall logic is something like:

- get keycode
- detect <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>
- if <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, ignore
- create map of keycodes with and without <kbd>shift</kbd> key

  - example map `{186 : ';', 187 : '=', 188 : ',', ....}`
  - need a separate map for <kbd>shift</kbd> key modifier
  - map needs to change depending on browser (especially Safari Mac which has keycodes like 60,000)
- if keycode is in map, return mapped key
- if keycode is not in map, normalize numbers, apply <kbd>shift</kbd> modifier key if necessary, return `String.fromCharCode(key)`

It's not a simple solution, which is why I'm looking for a pre-made one :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you willing to use jQuery?

```
$("input").bind("keydown",function(e){ var value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); }
```

I believe that switching to the keypress event would solve the issue mentioned in your comment. Would the code below meet your requirments?

```
$("input").bind("keypress",function(e){ var value = this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); }
```

Comment: won't work since jQuery doesn't normalize the charCode, only the keyCode.  The issues here are many, but ignoring the fact that different internationalized keyboards have different keycodes: "1" above "Q" is different than "1" on the numeric pad (your above code would return "1" or "a" depending on which is pressed).  "A" is "Shift+a" in the keydown event, etc...  The logic isn't all that complicated, there are just many, many different cases and different browsers act differently...

Comment: You don't need jQuery at all.

Comment: Yeah, jQuery adds absolutely nothing to this answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've been wondering the same thing for years. Recently I got fed up with having to look up keycodes for events that I wrote a module called [keysight](https://github.com/fresheneesz/keysight) that translates `keypress`, `keydown`, and `keyup` events into characters and keys respectively.

Example:

```
 element.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    var character = keysight(event).char
 })
```

It doesn't ignore anything on ctrl, so you'd have to do that manually if you want. But it does all the rest of the logic you gave.